"helmet" module activates the automatics redirect from "http://localhost" to "https://localhost" without possibility of manual correction
After I have activated the helmet module, the browser stops to display on http://localhost:3000/ and other ports of the localhost:

If more exactly, when open http://localhost:3000/, the browser automatically redirects to https://localhost:3000/. Also, if manually correct https://localhost:3000/ to http://localhost:3000/, the browser will return to https://localhost:3000/. But most important fact is the browser keep this behavior for all projects, not only for one when the HTTPS protocol support and actually enabled and helmet module used. It is problematic to provide the HTTPS support for all projects in local development mode.
I understand that this behavior is for security when surfing the internet, but it is the  interfering behavior when locally developing something when helmet module and HTTPS not using (actually, it is impossible to use same browser).

Helmet maintainer here. You can fix this by clearing your browser's HSTS cache (look it up, depends on your browser). I added a short line to the README to help future people with this problem.

@Marc Thank you for the comment. I understand that helmet forces browser to use HTTPS. The problem is, such behavior required only for the specific projects, not for everything that being served on localhost.

@EvanHahn Thank you for the support. I have cleared the Chrome cache and problem has been solved. Would you please to submit the answer? I'll accept and upvote it.

Helmet maintainer here.
You can fix this by clearing your browser's HSTS cache. See this guide.
This is happening because Helmet sets the Strict-Transport-Security header, abbreviated to "HSTS". HSTS hooks your browser on HTTPS for a period of time, typically a year or more. For example, if you visit https://example.com which sets the Strict-Transport-Security header, later visiting http://example.com will automatically redirect you.
Presumably, you visited https://localhost:3000 with HSTS at some point. This means that visiting http://localhost:3000 will automatically be redirected. Clearing your HSTS will reset this, allowing you to visit the insecure HTTP URL again.

Thank you for the answer! Accept & upvote, as I have promised.
